# How can I add file/folder icons?

Tags: themes, icons

How can I create new icons for files or folders? I can add them to the icon theme, so that I can access them by saying iconname in a launcher or notification, but I don't know how to make them show up in nautilus. As an example, I want to set an icon for the Ubuntu One folder, like how Pictures and Documents and so on have specific icons.

I realize I could change it manually, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your interested in creating icons packs you should look [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html). Another good resource is  http://gnome-look.org/